# Detect a video in webview in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

Is there a way to detect a video, playing in webview in react native?
What I want to do is open a site in webview in my react native application which is no issue at all. The issue is how to detect if a video is present on the webpage or detect it after I play a video on that webpage so I can write a function to download that video.